# Chrome extension no longer works - getting Uncaught ReferenceError when calling content script function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, referenceerror

I've found this site very useful over the years and now I have a situation that I can't seem to solve and haven't found an answer for. Hopefully I'm not missing something simple here.

I've been working on a Chrome extension for some time now which has been working without issues. I decided to branch off the main development and do some clean-up and add more features which were working last week and I don't recall changing anything aside from sorting the code into directories and adjusting manifest.json but suddenly I'm getting an Uncaught ReferenceError.

When a user browses to an empty internal page (page only contains HTML and BODY tags), the extension injects a bunch of html and the content script along with jQuery and a few other add-ons. The user uses a select list to choose a tool to run which calls a function in the content script - this is where I'm getting the error. Chrome DevTools shows all the sources being loaded so I'm not sure what has happened.

The content script is working as it runs the ajax call and updates the HTML body but I can't figure out why the onchange javascript functional call isn't working. Has something changed where I need to add the select tag and associated function call from the content script rather than injecting it with the HTML source?

Sites and function names changed for privacy concerns.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "0.2",
  "description": "Add-on function",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", 
                  "tabs", 
                  "declarativeContent", 
                  "storage",
                  "webRequest",
                  "http://site1.mysite.com/",
                  "http://site2.mysite.com/"],

  "options_ui": {"page": "options/options.html",
                 "open_in_tab": false
                },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["javascript/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", 
                "background/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "http://site2.mysite.com/my_dir/blank.html"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "js": ["javascript/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", 
               "javascript/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js", 
               "javascript/datatables/fixedheader/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js",
               "content/content.js" ],
        "css": ["javascript/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"]  
      }
    ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128":"images/get_started128.png"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": ["content/*",
                               "data/*",
                               "javascript/*", 
                               "images/*"]


}
```

**content.html**

```
....html, head, style tags and content
<body>
<div id="header">
  <select id="my_tool" onchange="my_tool_select(this)">
    <option value="0">Choose Tool </option>
    <!--<option value="1">Tool 1</option>-->
    <option value="2">Tool 2</option>
    <!-- <option value="3">Tool 3</option>-->
    <option value="4">Tool 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
.... lots of other HTML and closing body and html tags
```

**content.js**

```
// Function to initialize the content script
window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false);

function initialize(event) {
    .... other initialization code  
    $.ajax({
        url: chrome.extension.getURL('content/content.html'),
        success: function(data) {        
            $(data).appendTo(document.body);
        }
    });
    .... more initialization code
}

function my_tool_select(tool_option) {
    if ( tool_option == 1 ) {
        ...do something for the selected tool_option
    }
    else if (and so on) 
    ....
}
```

Comment: I've also injected the _<select>...</select>_ code via the content script and still get the same error.

Comment: `onchange="my_tool_select(this)"` will invoke my_tool_select in the page context, not in the content script (its JS environment is isolated from the page). There was a [bug in Chrome 71](https://crbug.com/912069) fixed in 72, which erroneously reversed this behavior. The solution is to stop using the inline handlers in html, and instead attach the listeners programmatically in your content script via $(...).on(), for example.

Comment: I started this extension from an existing HTML page and throughout the process, I was taking note of the contexts in which everything was running. You get used to it working and not thinking about something so trivial but you are right, the page context shouldn't be able to call anything from the context script.  Adding the $(...).on() change event fixed the issue. I guess the company pushed out the Chrome update over the weekend. Thanks for the tip.